# Cannot resolve symbol 'BillingResponse'

Tags: java, android, billing, android-billing

I have implemented Billing Library from the following url
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#java

I am getting error on this line

```
if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponse.OK) {
```

it says `Cannot resolve symbol 'BillingResponse'`

here is the complete code from above link

```
billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
@Override
public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponse.OK) {
        // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
    }
}
@Override
public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
    // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
    // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
}
});
```

I have added following dependency in my apps `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'
}
```

but I am getting error

I cannot even import it manually

```
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.BillingResponse;
```

I know its simple solution is to just replace

```
BillingResponse.OK
```

with

```
BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
```

but my question is why its not given in documentation then?

Comment: Have you tried `import static com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.BillingResponse`

Comment: i have tried and i have it mentioned in my question

Answer (score 6):

I checked the source codes and figured out the correct code.

Though the code on google documentation says `billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponse.OK` it should be `billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK`

So all you need to do is replace `BillingResponse.OK` with `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK`